# Azure Data Studio - intellisence do not see tables in schema other than dbo

Tags: intellisense, azure-data-studio

Do you know any way to force intellisence in Azure Data Studio to find tables in custom schemas?
[image]

As you can see I have tables:

- dbo.TableC
- schemaA.TableB

When typing a query, only TableC is found by intellisence.
I know that full SQL Server Management Studio does not do this by default as well but there are some extensions that do this (e.q. SqlComplete). Is there anything for Azure Data Studio with similar functionalities?

**Update:**

I created an issue on Azure Data Studio github. It's here: https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/18514

Comment: If you have created a new schema, you should close & open the connection just to refresh the info or right-click on the server and 'Refresh'.

Comment: @McNets, it doesn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

You may need to refresh the IntelliSense cache. Previously in SSMS, this was easily achievable via the shortcut `CTRL+SHIFT+R` but it seems that's no longer the case in Azure Data Studio.

Rather, in Azure Data Studio, you need to open the Command Palette, type in `intellisense`, and then you should be able to click on `Refresh IntelliSense Cache` as per [this answer by AMtwo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/298418/150011) on a similar question:

> To do this in ADS, press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` to bring up the *Command Palette*, and type `intellisense`. The drop down list will filter so you can select `Refresh IntelliSense Cache` from the listed options.

Perhaps there's a way to [create a dedicated shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-ver15) to this specific command too.

Comment: nope, it doesn't help. TableB is still not visible on the suggestions list.

Comment: @GrzegorzM Are you using the latest version of Azure Data Studio?

Comment: Yes I do, version 1.34.0.